# Capital letter with android:keyOutputText?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, ime

I am developing a language specific softkeyboard in android. My language has two letter characters such as 'ch' and 'ng'. I am using the following xml code to display and output the required characters

```
<Key android:keyOutputText="ng" android:keyLabel="ng"/>
```

But the output is only in small letters even if its the first letter in a sentence or when using the SHIFT key. How can i fix this? The required output would be to make only the first letter capital when its the first letter of a sentence or using shift key (eg. Ngaiteh), but to make it appear all capital when using capslock (eg. NGAITEH)

I know its quite easy to use the normal english keyboard and just type the required characters one by one, but this will really improve the typing speed for my language. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use xml attribute `android:codes` on the key rather than `android:keyOutputText` and then on override the behavior on method `onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes)` `OnKeyboardActionListener`

```
if (NG_KEYCODE == primaryCode) {
        if(keyboardView.isShifted()){
            getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                    "NG", 1);
        }else{
            getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                    "ng", 1);
        }
        updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
    }
```